# Why the max size of localStorage can be different on a same browser?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, local-storage

I write a script to test the max size of localStorage in my current browser (Chrome) with ReactJS, but it seems that the max size is not determined by the size in bytes, but the number of items in localStorage.

With the following code, the console will print `5242000` which is about `5MB`:

```js
// run on Chrome
let i = 0;
try {
    for (i = 5000000; i <= 6000000; i+=1000) {
        localStorage.setItem('test', new Array(i+1).join('a'));
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.error(i-1000);
    console.error(localStorage.getItem('test').length);
    console.error(localStorage.getItem('test'));
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

[image]

But if you change the code to:

```js
// same ...
for (i = 5000000; i <= 6000000; i+=1000) {
        localStorage.setItem('test', new Array(i+1).join('汉'));
    }
// same code ...
```

[image]

The console will still print `5242000`, which means it's about 15MB in size. Because each Chinese character ('汉') takes 3 bytes in utf-8, or in utf-16 it takes more than 1 byte(I don't remember).

Is there anything wrong with my code? Or I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason:

`localStorage` calculates its size limit based on the number of UTF-16 code units, not bytes. You can use the `length` property to get the number of code units in a string.

```js
function setLocalStorageSize() {
    localStorage.clear();
    if (localStorage && !localStorage.getItem('size')) {
        let i = 0;
        try {
            // Roughly 10240000 UTF-16 code units.
            for (i = 250; i <= 10000; i += 250) {
                // A character is 1B, (i * 1024) = i * 1KB
                localStorage.setItem('test', new Array((i * 1024) + 1).join('a'));
            }
        } catch (e) {
            localStorage.removeItem('test');
            // size in utf-16 code units, not bytes.
            localStorage.setItem('size', String(i - 250));
            console.log('localStorage size: ' + (i - 250) + '*1024 code units');
        }
    }
}
// will print: 5000*1024 code units
```

If you change the code above to:

```js
localStorage.setItem('test', new Array((i * 1024) + 1).join('汉'));
```

Still will print: 5000*1024 code units, because `汉` is 1 UTF-16 code unit same as `a`.

But if you change the code above to:

```js
localStorage.setItem('test', new Array((i * 1024) + 1).join(''));
```

Will print: 2500*1024 code units, because  is 2 UTF-16 code units.